# Apply with multiple arguments, overloading

Tags: r, dataset

I have a dataset comprised of clinics with each clinic is comprised of doctors, performing procedures on patients.

I have written to perform analyses on the dataset filtering for clinic lists or doctor lists (a simple one is below):

```
num.of <- function(x.doctor, x.clinic){


if (!missing(x.clinic)){
    df_filter <- filter(df_clean, clinic == x.clinic)
  }
  if (!missing(x.doctor)) {
    df_filter <- filter(df_clean, doctor == x.doctor)
  }
  num_doctor <- length(unique(df_filter$doctor))
  num_surveys <- nrow(df_filter)
  num_procedure <- length(unique(df_filter$PPID))
  result <- setNames(c(num_doctor, num_surveys, num_procedure), c("num_doctor", "num_surveys", "num_procedure"))
  return(result)
}
```

I am attempting to call on these functions with **either** a list of doctors or a list of clinics:

```
sapply(doctor_list, num.of, x.clinic = NULL)
```

However, the function only works when the 'first' argument is passed through, i.e. the function above does not work, but this does:

```
sapply(clinic_list, num.of, x.doctor = NULL)
```

If the arguments are reversed when writing the initial function, the opposite of the above examples is true.

The functions are fed only one set of arguments at a time: Either a list for x.doctor or a list for x.clinic.

How can I rewrite my functions please so that apply works  x.clinic and in a separate function call for x.doctor?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
num.of <- function(x, data, type = c("doctor", "clinic")) {
  type <- match.arg(type)
  df_filter <-
    if (type == "doctor") {
      filter(data, doctor == x)
    } else {
      filter(data, clinic == x)
    }
  num_doctor <- length(unique(df_filter$doctor))
  num_surveys <- nrow(df_filter)
  num_procedure <- length(unique(df_filter$PPID))
  result <- setNames(c(num_doctor, num_surveys, num_procedure), c("num_doctor", "num_surveys", "num_procedure"))
  return(result)
}
```

This enables an explicit and clear call:

```
sapply(doctor_list, num.of, data = df_clean, type = "doctor")
sapply(clinic_list, num.of, data = df_clean, type = "clinic")
```

I took the liberty of helping with a scope breach: accessing `df_clean` from inside the function may work but can present problems in the future. It makes the function very context-dependent and inflexible in the presence of multiple datasets. Even if you are 100% certain you will always always always have `df_clean` in your calling (or global) environment for this case, it's a good habit (among "Best Practices <sup>TM</sup>").

If this doesn't work, then you might need to make a more [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that we can actually test the function. Since you may not want to include actual data, it makes things incredibly easier for everyone else if you make it generic-as-ever, with simple names and simple example data.